# Misbehaving of the date parsing in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a java class inside the jar file that is in a JBoss server which invoked through a bash file as follows.

```
java -cp /com/site/domain/TimeFormatter.jar packOne.subPack.Test
```

But I got an error when parsing the below date in there.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 29 Jan 2014 21:00:00 GMT"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
```

**Java CODE :**

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z").parse("Sun, 26 Jan 2014 21:00:00 GMT");
System.out.println("main().date : " + date);
```

What am I missing here? I read many posts about the misbehaving of the SimpleDateFormat. But this is some thing that I didn't find among those posts.

Note : I thought this is because of the java version change or some thing. But, I executed the same program with different versions in my machine. It worked perfectly.
Server java version "1.5.0_22"

**locale details :**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine for me, and I think it's not a *Java version*-related issue... but more of a `Locale` problem :)

Specifying `Locale.ENGLISH` for your `SimpleDateFormat` should definitively make it work. For example, you could do:

```
final Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("Sun, 26 Jan 2014 21:00:00 GMT");
```

---

As specified in the [javadoc entry for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), the date parsing is *locale-sensitive*. I have to admit that I don't exactly know how your string does not match your `Locale,` but we can investigate further if... we know what your default `Locale` actually is :)

Comment: Can you explain why it errs without specifying a Locale?

Comment: Assuming the default locale is not Locale.ENGLISH, SimpleDateFormat expects day and month names in some other language (treating English ones as wrong).

Comment: Hmm... I didn't try that thing. Let me try and update in a while

Comment: Yes, @LorenzoGatti's explanation is the best we can achieve without some further investigation about one's particular `Locale`.

Comment: I didn't upload the changes and tested in the production server yet. But I got the locale information from the server. Added in the question.

Comment: I uploaded the change and tested in there. It works now. Thank you very much. Learnt a very important new thing!

Answer (score 1):

The modern Java date and time classes had not quite come out when this question was first asked and answered. I should like to contribute the modern solution that I recommend using nowadays.

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed, 29 Jan 2014 21:00:00 GMT", 
            DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
```

I was about to write the same about the need for a locale as in the other answer, but then I saw the light: your date-time string conforms to the RFC 1123 format. This is built-in with Java-8 and later and therefore also with [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the modern classes to Java 6 and 7. `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` works in English always, independent of locale. So the above is all you need. Tested on a computer with Danish default locale.